# not able to apply foreign key constraint in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys

I can run the below query and there are no nulls in the user_id column in the result -

```
select c.*,r.user_id from chat_group_users c left join roleuser r 
on c.user_id = r.user_id;
```

But I cannot apply the foreign key constraint and mysql just says

```
Error Code: 1215. Cannot add foreign key constraint
```

The command i wrote -

```
ALTER TABLE chat_group_users 
ADD CONSTRAINT fk_roleuser FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES roleuser (user_id)
ON DELETE cascade  ON UPDATE cascade;
```

The table structures -

```
CREATE TABLE `roleuser` (
`User_ID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`UserNM` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
`UserPS` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
`r_username` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
`UGroup` varchar(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Usar',
`FirstName` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
`LastName` varchar(45) NOT NULL,   
 PRIMARY KEY (`User_ID`),
 UNIQUE KEY `Index_2` (`UserNM`),
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=50 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


CREATE TABLE `chat_group_users` (
`auto_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`group_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`user_id` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
`is_admin` varchar(5) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`auto_id`),
 UNIQUE KEY `unique_user_group` (`user_id`,`group_id`),
 KEY `fc_group_id` (`group_id`),
 CONSTRAINT `fc_group_id` FOREIGN KEY (`group_id`) 
 REFERENCES `chat_group`(`auto_id`) 
 ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
  )ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=21 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

Comment: Include relevant table structures.

Comment: make sure that your user_id columns are of the same datatype

Comment: `User_ID` has3 capital letters `ADD CONSTRAINT fk_roleuser FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES roleuser (user_id)` has none.

Comment: @wildplasser that doesn't matter :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

missed the unsigned on the chat_group_users -

```
 `User_ID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, ...
```